# post data using curl command

Tags: json, node.js, curl

I have tried posting data in curl using this command:

```
curl -X POST http://x.x.x.x:1111/send --data [{'virtual':'5555'}]
```

Then I am getting a response in node like this:

```
{ '{virtual:5555}': '' }
```

How to convert this to array? I have tried `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` but I get an `Unexpected token o` error as result.

Any idea how to post the json data in curl command?
I also tried with:

```
curl ... -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[{"virtual":"5555"}]' "http://x.x.x.x:1111/send"
```

Then you should receive the raw body as `'[{"virtual":"5555"}]'`:

```
var body = JSON.parse(req.body);
```

or, already parsed (if you use a middleware). And you can use it:

```
console.log(body.length); // 1
console.log(body[0].virtual); // '5555'
```

Comment: when i use console.log(request) there is no parameter like rawbody. so how i can parse undefined variable

Comment: it was an example... I changed it to `req.body`. mind it could be already parsed

Comment: i also tried with req.body, i am getting response like this { '{virtual:5555}': ' ' } with this result i need virtual value .when i use req.body.virtual it gives undefined. also used console.log(body[0].virtual); this result also gives same result 'undefined'.

Comment: Please post your code and the exact content of `req.body`

Comment: this is the curl command i used curl -XPOST http://xxx.xxx.x.x:xxxx/send --data [{'virtual':'5555'}].  this is the response { '{virtual:5555}': '' }
i need virtual value.when use req.body.virtual it get's undefined as result.